# Long if statement, a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this horrible verbose code that runs on mouse move:

```
if (distance < 215) {
  moveSmile(1)
  }

if (distance < 200) {
 moveSmile(2)
}

if (distance < 185) {
 moveSmile(3)
}

if (distance < 170) {
 moveSmile(4)
}

if (distance < 155) {
  moveSmile(5)
}

if (distance < 140) {
  moveSmile(6)
}
```

And the function it calls:

```
 function moveSmile (frameNum) {
   mouthX = startMouthPos + mouthFrameWidth * frameNum
   $('#mouth').css('background-position', -mouthX + 'px -359px')
 }
```

I am moving a div's background position at 15px intervals the closer it get's to the target div.  Is there a way to make this shorter and more efficient?

Comment: why not `else if`?  If `distance < 140` it's going to result in multiple calls to the `moveSmile` method.. is that what you want?

Comment: use a `switch` statement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
moveSmile(Math.ceil((215 - distance) / 15));
```

Comment: Yep, I was thinking in something like that. You can map somewhat distance => frameNum and then limit the result if necesary. :-)

Comment: If you take a closer look to the code, it is not an else if, but a serie of if. So if distance is `139`, it will run `moveSmile(1);moveSmile(2);moveSmile(3)` and so on. I don't know if it is a mistake from the OP.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Good catch!! Assuming it's intentional, I'll have to edit my post a bit.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I don't think it is. Looking at the contents of `moveSmile`, only the last call will have a lasting effect.

Comment: @Matt true, did not see he posted his fn!

Comment: This works well thank you, I need to set a minimum range, I guess I could just warp it in an if statement

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick formula should do the trick:

```
moveSmile(Math.ceil((215 - distance) / 15);
```

```
(230 - 215) / 15 == 1
(230 - 200) / 15 == 2
...
(230 - 140) / 15 == 6
```

Now, `Math.ceil` is used to round values from steps that aren't neatly separated by `15`, up to the corresponding value.

Comment: JS doesn't do integer division, so you must round the number in some way.

Comment: `distance` as 214 returns `1.0666666666666667`. You need some rounding of some sort.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, in Chrome's console, in fact my testing was why my answer was not the first one. :-)

Comment: Oh, whoops, forgot about distances that aren't at the steps of 15, just a moment...

Comment: Almost good edit. You are still missing the edge case between `<` vs `<=`.

Comment: There's really no point in editing my answer, now that you answered with what's basically a fix to my code, @ChrisJester-Young... Ah well...

Comment: @Cerbrus There is still a point: I can retract my downvote. :-)

Comment: Didn't look at it that way, yet :P I'm curious why both our answers are downvoted, though...

Comment: Yeah, people are strange that way. :-P

Answer (score -1):

Make an array and loop through the keys.

```
var bob = [215, 200 ... 140];
for(var i = 0; i < bob.length; i++) 
{
   if(distance < bob[i]) {
       moveSmile(i+1);
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, give a reason why.

Comment: This seems to work. Not sure why it's been downvoted, but I'm also not sure why you've made the array elements strings. It would work fine as `[215, 200, ... 140]`.

Comment: It was supossed to be an object first when I realized it was sequential.  Other answers have pointed out that it's also decrementing by 15 which I also hadn't noticed.  Edit incoming.